# Disable automatic oEmbed of a youtube url within the content

Tags: oembed

I run a small site based on wp with user generated content. Users often submit youtube links. And then wordpress automatically converts these links to videos which is **unwanted in our case**. I need to override this automatic behavior so that the submitted youtube links remains in `plain text urls` ?

I found out that I could [remove the oembed provider](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_remove_provider) itself with something like `wp_oembed_remove_provider('http://www.youtube.com/oembed')` but I am stumped at how do I use this in my case where `$content` is the string that contains the url as well as the submitted post content ? The [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_remove_provider) doesnot says much about it. Could someone give me an example of how this can be done.

In other words I need the oEmbed to skip any youtube link/s in content. Also please let me know if there is a better/more efficient way of solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

disable the oembed like below in functions.php :

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', array( $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed' ), 8 );
```

Thanks!

Comment: we need the embed to work for other providers except youtube. How can we do it please ?

Comment: Please try using this will disable your youtube one and rest like Twitter will still work.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer didn't work in my case. URLs were still being converted to embeds in the post editor.

By looking at the source of [wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L23) where this stuff is handled, I found that there are some other things at play here:

```
// Hack to get the [embed] shortcode to run before wpautop()
add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'run_shortcode' ), 8 );

// Shortcode placeholder for strip_shortcodes()
add_shortcode( 'embed', '__return_false' );

// Attempts to embed all URLs in a post
add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'autoembed' ), 8 );

// After a post is saved, cache oEmbed items via AJAX
add_action( 'edit_form_advanced', array( $this, 'maybe_run_ajax_cache' ) );
```

What fixed the issue for me was disabling these in my theme files like so:

```
remove_shortcode( 'embed' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', [ $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed' ], 8 );
remove_filter( 'the_content', [ $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'run_shortcode' ], 8 );
remove_action( 'edit_form_advanced', [ $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'maybe_run_ajax_cache' ] );
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for providing a full and correct asnwer.

Comment: After several other solutions I found didn't work for me, this one is what did. Thanks.

Comment: Yay! After searching for forever, this answer finally worked for me.