# How to disable YouTube (and any other oembed) embeding in the editor

Tags: editor, oembed

It is easy to disable oEmbed on the front end [Disable automatic oEmbed of a youtube url within the content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202496/disable-automatic-oembed-of-a-youtube-url-within-the-content), but this leaves us with the editor shows a video (in the case of youtube) where on the front end there will be only a URL.

How can it be disabled on the editor side as well?

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to disable oEmbeds would be

```
add_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', '__return_false' );
```

If you want to disable it for all external links then try:

```
/**
 * Disable oEmbeds for external links 
 */
add_filter( 'pre_oembed_result', function( $result, $url, $args )
{    
    if( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) !==  parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        $result = false;

    return $result;

}, 999, 3 );
```

This is a modification from a more detailed answer I posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233045/26350).

Comment: hmm, anything more refined then that? will be great if I can still have it working on pages but not on some custom post type that should be associated with basically text only content.

Comment: You mean how to disable it during post editing in the backend, for a given post type?. We could e.g. check for _POST variables like `post_ID`, `type=embed`, `action=parse-embed` and `shortcode`, within our `pre_oembed_result` callback, but then we would need to remove the post type from `wp_ajax_oembed_cache()` through the `embed_cache_oembed_types` filter or check GET variables. Sounds hackish. Maybe there are other ways to stop the ajax calls for given post types?

Comment: will take a look layer, right now it actually do not work for me and I have no time to check if it is some caching, and it is not a priority, just a nice yo have ...